# Sharing parameters of an activation across layers of a neural network

Tags: neural-network, keras, activation-function

Keras now provides advanced parametric activation layers like Leaky-ReLU PReLU.
Each time I add this layer to a sequential model, an additional trainable parameter is added to graph.

How can I make sure the trainable parameter of activation is shared across all layers.

Thanks